# Redim Preserve array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, jagged-arrays

I am adding elements to a listOF and then converting that list to an array.  I then need to add a specific number of elements to each of the arrays while also preserving the data in each element.  I am close but not there yet.

This is not working.  That data is preserved in the elements but the code is not adding the specified number of elements to each array (each array needs to = 51).

Any help is appreciated as always.  Thank you.

```
 'Add an element to each ListOf(Integer) based on how many rows are in the DataGridView
        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvStepTest.Rows
            accels.Add(r.Cells(0).Value) : decels.Add(r.Cells(1).Value) : Speeds.Add(r.Cells(2).Value)
            holds.Add(r.Cells(3).Value) : flows.Add(r.Cells(4).Value) : Temps.Add(r.Cells(5).Value)
        Next

        'Convert each ListOf(Integer) to an Array
        accels.TrimExcess() : accelRates = accels.ToArray
        decels.TrimExcess() : decelRates = decels.ToArray
        Speeds.TrimExcess() : spindleSpeeds = Speeds.ToArray
        holds.TrimExcess() : holdTimes = holds.ToArray
        flows.TrimExcess() : flowRates = flows.ToArray
        Temps.TrimExcess() : oilTemps = Temps.ToArray

        'Now determine the number of elements to add to each of the arrays so that the length of each array = 51
        num = (51 - accelRates.Length)

        'Now add the number of elements to each array based on the number calculated above, while also preserving the data
        'already in each element in each of the arrays.  New elements added should have values = 0.
        Dim jaggedArray()() = New Integer(5)() {accelRates, decelRates, spindleSpeeds, holdTimes, flowRates, oilTemps}
        For Each [Array] In jaggedArray
            ReDim Preserve Array(Array.Length + num)
        Next
```

Comment: Try [**`Array.Resize()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Also step through your code using a debugger to verify all variables.

Comment: Is there a reason you are wanting to increment the size of the array (which is expensive) instead of adding the extra items to your list before converting it to an array ?

Comment: Mark,  thanks for the feedback.  No, no reason, hence I already went back and changed it so that I am adding the extra elements to the list and then converting to the array.  So, I'm accomplishing what I need to even if it is not as originally planned.  Still, thanks for the catch. With that said, I would still like to make the original work just for my own knowledge and may need to use it at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is the redim statement you are setting the total number of items in the array, hence all you need to do is redim the array the size that you want, no need to do math, remembering that an array is 0 based which means that setting an array size of 51 with the redim statement will actually have 52 records. This is a quick little test to show what I mean.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim accels As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()
        accels.AddRange({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})
        Dim accelrates = accels.ToArray()
        Dim num As Integer = (50) ' Index is zero based there for use 50
        ReDim Preserve accelrates(num)
    End Sub
End Module
```

or you can use `Array.Resize` as VisualVincent suggested

```
Array.Resize(accelrates, 51)
```

In looking a little further, it appears your `For Each` statement isn't working as you expect. I would change it to a `For` statement something like this.

```
For x = 0 To jaggedArray.Count - 1
    ReDim Preserve jaggedArray(x)(50)
Next
```